# Search for a join table where one item is the same, the second item is equal to one of two records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

We have a `Conversation`, and a `User` model. There's a join table `ConversationsUser`. A convo can have only two users. I want to create a method that will return an existing conversation, or create a new one.

Given two `User`s, I want to do a query like: Find two `ConversationsUser` records whose `conversation_id`s are equal for both records, and `user_id` is `user1` and `user2`.

How would I got about constructing this query?

Comment: Please have a look at the answer, let me know if you need any further guidance, Feel free to accept/upvote answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

It can be maintained with a unique column(`key: text`) between two users of a conversation, there may be easy solution also,

```
class Conversation < ApplicationRecord
  # Associations
  has_many :conversation_users, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :conversation_users


  # Validations
  #add key:text in conversations table
  validates :key, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}, :allow_blank => true

  # Callbacks
  before_validation :update_key

  def update_key
    self.key = Conversation.key_for_users(self.users)
  end

  # method that will return an existing conversation, or create a new one.
  def self.between(users)
    key = self.key_for_users(users)

    conversation = Conversation.where(key: key).first_or_create
    conversation.users = users
    conversation.save
    return conversation
  end
end
```

=> A query like: Find two ConversationsUser records whose conversation_ids are equal for both records, and user_id is user1 and user2.

```
conversation = Conversation.between([user1, user2])
```